# Kafka connect read value based on a key and write to HDFS

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

1. Is there any way to sink only specific event type from a kafka topic to HDFS filtering the remaining types using kafka connect HDFS connector?
2. can we segregate the input events based on some key and write to different partitions. So that the values of specific key goes to specific partition?
3. can we use the keys stored in schema registry to get the values in the topic specific to particular key for avro format data? Kindly let me know if my understanding needs clarity.

**If Kafka connect does not have this features can this be implemented by using kafka streams**?And please help with some documentation if it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to sink only specific event type from a kafka topic to HDFS filtering the remaining types using kafka connect HDFS connector?

Kafka Connect has transforms for manipulating messages, but it is not meant for filtering. That's commonly done by Kafka Streams or KSQL

> can we segregate the input events based on some key and write to different partitions,So that the values of specific key goes to specific partition?

The `FieldPartitioner` class mentioned in the Confluent documentation does this (warning: I believe it only does top-level fields, not nested JSON or Avro record fields)

> can we use the keys stored in schema registry to get the values in the topic specific to particular key for avro format data?

I don't understand the question, but HDFS Connect, by default, ignores the Kafka message key when writing the data, so I'm going to say no.

Kafka data isn't indexed by key, it's partitioned by it, which means if you did use the DefaultPartioner rather than the FieldPartitioner, then all keys would land in a single filesystem path by Kafka partition. Only then would you be able to query, not by the key, though, but *by the partition*. for example using Spark or Hive. Again, that's the default behavior - you can use a Transform, as mentioned previously, to add the Kafka key into the data, which you can then query by it

Comment: One other note is that you might consider putting different event types in different topics instead of having one topic that you have to filter. You can subscribe to multiple topics with the connector and this strategy might simplify your scenario.

Comment: That's assuming there's multiple event types. One could be just be filtering by fields within one type

Comment: Yep totally, I think the original post suggests there are multiple types in the topic but of course it depends on the scenario :)

Comment: Thank you!! Can we use the key in the Field partition-er to partition based on keys?

Comment: If you use a Transform to move the key into the message value, then should be possible. See https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive

Comment: Thanks you!! this option looks fine  Transform to move the key into the message value but still is it possible to use transformation ReplaceField :  org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Key -- to filter the values based on keys? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html#replacefield

Comment: @ crickey_007 is there any other way that can be used to over ride the default behavior of kafka connect to write both key and value to HDFS file for evrey record, Some thing like this property --property print.key=true

Comment: Connect must write a SinkRecord object. A SinkRecord only has one value. You need that archive transformation to move the key into a single SinkRecord object value. After that transform, you're welcome to change the value struct however you want. Multiples transforms can be applied to messages